# A beginner questions about printf, java

Tags: java, string, printf

I'm learning Java by myself and through tutorials online.
Just wondering in a printf statement, what does the different %s, %d, %15, %7, %12.2(and so on...) mean?

Couldn't find any explanation anywhere online, so I'm turning to you.

Comment: Don't believe this : Couldn't find any explanation anywhere online, so I'm turning to you guys.

Comment: check the first link of this [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+printf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=lfGHVcvnD46duQSO6oK4Aw) search. -1

Comment: %15, %7, %12.2....may be JCP has approved for new format :P.

Comment: If you can't find explanations about common things like that online, you should learn to use search engines better before you attempt to learn Java. I am being honest here. You'll be able to solve Java (or any) problems faster yourself, instead of relying on other people's help.

Comment: how do you know these symbols exist but don't know what they mean? That wasn't in the tutorial? Doesn't pass the sniff test.

Answer (score 1):

Actually printf is used in java if you are using formatting as he was asking about in his question.

```
double number = 10.5555555;
System.out.printf("The number 10.555555 rounded to two decimal places is %2f", number);
```

Now as far as the symbols, the ones I know are %d = integer, %f= double, %s= string.

Answer (score 0):

See, printf isn't in Java. printf is used in C and C++ and the like. Java uses System.out.println(), etc.

If you're learning Java, you needn't worry about printf. ;)
Even those things you wanted to know about - they're not in Java either.